# Where to research medieval leather armor?

Tags: medieval, armors

Has anyone any good resources for medieval armor? Specifically leather armor, and within the later 15th century and early 16th century.

Comment: History.SE might have better information on this

Comment: You'll find some info in our list of [worldbuilding resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/143606/40609). However, if you're looking for specific historical details, @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica is right, you should ask on [history.se].

Comment: Or just ask around any re-enactment groups on facebook. You'll probably get bombed with sources.